# Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp

Tags: hadoop

```
Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-MayPayne\mapred\staging\MayPayne2016979439\.staging to 0700
```

I'm getting this error  when the MapReduce job executing, I was using hadoop 1.0.4, then I got to  know it's a known issue and I tried this with the 1.2.0 but the issue still exists. Can I know a hadoop version that they have resolved this issue.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Are you sure this issue related to Hadoop version you are using?. 
what user id you are using to submit the MapReduce job? who the owner for `\tmp`?

Comment: Yeah, the user running the MapReduce job must be the owner of the directory you mentioned.

Comment: Where is the known issue tracked in Hadoop's tracker?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the hadoop-core jar file little bit. Changed the error causing method in FileUtil.java in hadoop-core.jar file and recompiled and included in my eclipse project. Now the error is gone. I suggest every one of you to do that.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the same exception while runing nutch-1.7 on windows 7.

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl11 -depth 1 -topN 5
```

The following steps worked for me

1. Download the pre-built JAR, patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win.jar, from the[Download](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win/downloads) section. You may get the steps for hadoop.
2. Copy patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win.jar to the ${NUTCH_HOME}/lib directory
3. Modify ${NUTCH_HOME}/conf/nutch-site.xml to enable the overriden implementation as shown below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
   <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>fs.file.impl</name>
           <value>com.conga.services.hadoop.patch.HADOOP_7682.WinLocalFileSystem</value>
           <description>Enables patch for issue HADOOP-7682 on Windows</description>
       </property>
    </configuration>
   ```
4. Run your job as usual (using Cygwin).

Answer (score 5):

Downloading [hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar) and putting it on nutcher's lib directory resolved the problem for me

(In case of windows) If still not solved for you, try using this [hadoop's patch](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win)

Comment: hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

set the below vm arguments

```
-Dhadoop.tmp.dir=<A directory location with write permission>
```

to override the default /tmp directory

Also using hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2) will solve the reported issue.