# Hadoop Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I'm running (or obviously trying to) Hadoop 1.2.1 on my Windows machine inside cygwin. Unfortunately there is something terribly wrong with my Hadoop. I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to execute simple Pig script on local mode.

```
Backend error message during job submission
-------------------------------------------
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-antonbelev\mapred\staging\antonbelev1696923409\.staging to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.mainLoopAction(PigJobControl.java:157)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:148)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:607)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

I assume that there is something wrong with the hadoop installation or configuration files, but I'm new to Hadoop so is just an assumption. Can someone help me to resolve this problem. Thank you! : )

PS Also why the path in the `\tmp\hadoop-antonbelev\mapred\staging\antonbelev1696923409\.staging to 0700` is using windows backslashes? I tried to find this file but it doesn't exists.

**UPDATE**:

Here I my config files:

**core-site.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>localhost:9100</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9101</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hadoop-env.sh:**

```
# Set Hadoop-specific environment variables here.

# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# optional.  When running a distributed configuration it is best to
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
# remote nodes.

# The java implementation to use.  Required.
 export JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07"

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Optional.
# export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=

# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
# export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=2000

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_OPTS=-server

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"
export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"
# export HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS=
# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
# export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS

# Extra ssh options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-o ConnectTimeout=1 -o SendEnv=HADOOP_CONF_DIR"

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
# export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/logs

# File naming remote slave hosts.  $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves by default.
# export HADOOP_SLAVES=${HADOOP_HOME}/conf/slaves

# host:path where hadoop code should be rsync'd from.  Unset by default.
# export HADOOP_MASTER=master:/home/$USER/src/hadoop

# Seconds to sleep between slave commands.  Unset by default.  This
# can be useful in large clusters, where, e.g., slave rsyncs can
# otherwise arrive faster than the master can service them.
# export HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP=0.1

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
#       the users that are going to run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is
#       the potential for a symlink attack.
# export HADOOP_PID_DIR=/var/hadoop/pids

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
# export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER

# The scheduling priority for daemon processes.  See 'man nice'.
# export HADOOP_NICENESS=10
```

I'm not sure if any other config files are relevant.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration files?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker I've updated my questions. Have I missed any other relevant config files?

Comment: What I can best say at this moment is to manually configure the hadoop property in core-site.xml
<property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>
  </property>

Comment: There is a 3rd party patch for this bug, as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18381218/150020

Comment: What was your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the file permissions of the folder you are using as hadoop tmp folder.
something like:

```
sudo chmod a+w /app/hadoop/tmp -R
```

Comment: it's a Windows machine.

Comment: winutils.exe chmod 777 pathTodhadoopBin 
this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please add this entry in core-site.xml like this

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
 <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
```

Problem with your configuration is tmp folder which hadoop is reading is under root or /tmp.